# System.InvalidOperationException: call Forms.Init() before this Xamarin iOS Hybrid project

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Hello I have an app I'm working on in both Xamarin iOS native and a piece of it in Xamarin Forms all I'm trying to do is when the user clicks contectbttn in my native part of the app it opens the xamrian froms class CountySelect. I'm getting this error when I click the button on the device following an app crash:

> System.InvalidOperationException: call Forms.Init() before this

here's the native Xamarin iOS code with the button's pressed:

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace App.iOS
{
    public partial class HomeView : UIViewController
    {
        public HomeView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {

        }
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();


            contactbttn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
                var secondViewController = App.GetSecondPage().CreateViewController();
                NavigationController.PushViewController(secondViewController, true);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Here's My app.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App
{
    public class App : Application
    {

        public static Page GetSecondPage()
        {
            var formsPage = new NavigationPage(new CountySelect());

            return formsPage;
        }
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            //MainPage = new MainPage();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new CountySelect());

        }



        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        public static object CountySelect()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT HERE'S THE AppDelegate code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

namespace App.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        public override UIWindow Window
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        // This method is invoked when the application is about to move from active to inactive state.
        // OpenGL applications should use this method to pause.
        public override void OnResignActivation(UIApplication application)
        {
        }
        // This method should be used to release shared resources and it should store the application state.
        // If your application supports background exection this method is called instead of WillTerminate
        // when the user quits.
        public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
        {
        }
        // This method is called as part of the transiton from background to active state.
        public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
        {
        }
        // This method is called when the application is about to terminate. Save data, if needed.
        public override void WillTerminate(UIApplication application)
        {
        }
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            Forms.Init();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call Forms.Init() before you use Forms.  This is usually done in your AppDelegate's FinishedLaunching() method.

Comment: I added it to the FinishedLauncheing method but now get this error and crash when clicking the contactbttn:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: you need ot figure out which variable is null, and then fix it